# Хранение данных приложения в памяти устройства

Tags: java, android, кэширование

Есть необходимость хранить данные пользователя на его же мобильном устройстве! Данные могут быть разные, картинки, текстовые файлы  и т.д.
Фактически мне нужно зарезервировать место на карте памяти или внутреннем хранилище устройства некоторое количество мегабайт. Т.е. мне нужен некий кэш приложения.

В интернете я чаще нахожу о том как делать подобные вещи используя `sharedpreferences` но по-моему, это не совсем то что  мне нужно!

Вопрос, какие есть механизмы для резервирования  и управления памятью  на мобильном устройстве.

Comment: А почему бы не создать папку на SD, назвать её `%ИМЯ_ПРИЛОЖЕНИЯ%` и не положить туда все ваши файлы?...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я так и сделал)  просто мне было интересно, может есть уже какие то готовые механизмы управления памятью  на устройстве.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` класс обычно используют для хранения небольшой информации, которая в свою очередь сохраняется непосредственно в самом приложении, по типу ключ-значение. Как правило здесь хранят id, name, и тд. Этот класс не требует никаких `permission`-ов.

В Вашем случае скорей всего надо использовать SQLite(если data регулярно обновляется и её надо хранить) для текстовых данных, для хранения ссылок на файлы, и SD-card для хранения самих файлов. Здесь требуется `permission` `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.  Но опять же, надо знать полную задачу, чтобы дать конкретный совет.

Comment: если совсем конкретно: то приложение чат, нужно: хранение контактов( имя, телефон, адрес) ,  сохранение переписки( фото, текстовые сообщения) в целом это все.

Comment: Тогда используйте Sqlite для хранения текстовой информации и sd-card для хранения фоток